# Javascript VArgs - not understanding arguments objects with unknown input

Tags: javascript, arguments, variadic-functions

So this is a bit of a newbie troubleshooting question. I am doing an exercise of freecodecamp, and I am having an issue parsing the input to my function. It's short, and I think I can cut to the chase if I just show you the code:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  console.log("---");
  console.log("arr: " + arr);
  var args = Array.from(arr);
  console.log(args);
  var in_i = arr[0];

  return in_i.filter(function (x) {
    if (args.indexOf(x) !== -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

which gives me in the console (and I think this is the strange part):

```
---
arr: 1,2,3,1,2,3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Clearly I'm not understanding something about [arguments objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), or else something is broken. In my experience, the latter is exceedingly uncommon. I would have expected the `Array.from(arr)` to give an array object: `[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `function destroyer(arr)` accepts only 1 parameter in the function  **destroyer** which is an array `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` and **ignore**  the other arguments `2, 3`. So, the `arr` is `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`.

If you need to access all the parameters passed to the function, then you can make use of `arguments` object which is an **array like** object. `arguments` would point to the array `[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]`. Following code should display the Arguments passed.

```js
function destroyer(arr, param2, param3) {
  // Remove all the values
   console.log(arguments);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

If your function takes 3 parameters as shown below, `param2, param3` have been added, then you can access the value 2, 3 inside your function.

```
function destroyer(arr, param2, param3) {
  // Remove all the values
  console.log("---");
  console.log("arr: " + arr);
  var args = Array.from(arr);
  console.log(args);
  var in_i = arr[0];

  return in_i.filter(function (x) {
    if (args.indexOf(x) !== -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I'm not sure you 100% got what I was trying to say, but your observation about the rest of the arguments being ignored was really helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the part that confused me was that on MDN, the use of the `arguments` variable was not just illustrative, it's a built-in variable. After @Agalo pointed out that the values I was getting on the console were just the array, it clicked for me.

The solution was to access the extra arguments through the built-in `arguments object` which automatically has the (reserved) name `arguments`. Code is like so (for completeness, I should note that I also had false and true switched in the return statements):

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  var args_l = arguments.length;
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  console.log(args);
  var in_i = args.shift();

  return in_i.filter(function (x) {
    if (args.indexOf(x) !== -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

To riff off of Agalo, you'll note you don't actually need the param2, param3 arguments in the function definition to get the exact same output:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
   console.log(arguments);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

At the risk of putting too fine a point on it:

```js
function args_tester(a) {
  console.log("a: " + a);
  console.log("arguments: " + arguments);
  console.log("arguments_as_array: " + Array.from(arguments));
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}

args_tester("a", "b", "c");
```